# JavaPOS Configuration with Symbol peripherals

Tags: java, javapos

I have a POS application that needs to be JavaPOS enabled.
Based on my research,I have concluded that there are vendors like `Epson` and `IBM` and many more which auto-configure the `jpos.xml` for that peripheral.This means that upon downloading the drivers from these vendors, there is a utility which configures the `jpos.xml` file.

However, there are other vendors like `Symbol` and `Posiflex` which do not provide us with the utility on downloading the relevant drivers and hence the need to configure the `jpos.xml` manually.

I need to know if the jar files for the peripheral need to be simply copied in the library folder of the POS application or also to be added to the POS application classpath.

Any clarity on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, Pos vendor generally provide their own upos driver (like ibm, nixdorf ...) and utility to configure jpos.xml.

If you want to integrate perihperal vendor jpos drivers you must :

1) add driver package to path and/or classpath depends if you have just jar or jar and dll

2) add an entry to the jpos.xml to provide a logicial  alias to use in your application
There are some thread in the kasstore forum which explain that.